# Rails: Database records with custom route...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a model, target, that holds a number of records that are timestamped.  On the corresponding controller, I list the months of those records by doing the following:

In **models/target.rb**

```
def month
   self.recorded_on.strftime('%B')
end
```

In **controllers/targets_controller.rb**

```
@records = Target.find :all
```

In **views/targets/index.html.haml**

```
%ul
  - @records.group_by(&:month).sort.each do |month, data|
    %li= link_to month, ''
```

That all works great for listing the available months for the records that I have.  Next, I want to be able to click on the month and get a report of all the records for that month, at the following path generated with year and the month: **/targets/2009/04**

How would I do this?

Comment: Okay, I think this is just a routing question, based on what I've found thus far.  I think I want something like: map.connect 'targets/:year/:month', { :controller => 'targets', :action => 'show', :year => /[0-9]{4}/, :month => /[0-9]{2}/ }... right? Then I can use params[:month] & params[:year] to pull in the right records on my show action? But I can't seem to get that route working... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some [named scopes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope) to your `Target` model to support finding by year and by month number. Something like:

```
class Target < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :by_month,
    lambda { |month| { :conditions => ['MONTH(recorded_on) = ?',
                        month] }}

  named_scope :by_year,
    lambda { |year| { :conditions => ['YEAR(recorded_on) = ?', year] }} 
  .
  .
  .
end
```

(Note that the conditions here are using MySQL syntax.)

Assuming you're using RESTful routes, set up a [named route](http://railscasts.com/episodes/34-named-routes) like the one below in your `config/routes.rb` file (make sure it's declared before the default route):

```
map.targets_by_month '/targets/:year/:month', :controller => 'targets',
                :requirements => { :year => /\d{4}/, :month => /\d{1,2}/ },
                :conditions => { :method => :get }
```

—You can use this route in your view like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Show April 2009 Targets', targets_by_month_path('2009', '04') %>
```

(Note that the leading zero for the month is optional because of the `:requirements` regular expression in the named route defined above)

Finally, in your `TargetsController`, set up the `index` action to use the named_scopes defined earlier:

```
def index
  @records = Target.by_year(params[:year]).by_month(params[:month])
  .
  .
  .
end
```

Comment: I get this error for the named_scope's bit: SQLite3::SQLException: no such function: YEAR: SELECT * FROM "targets" WHERE ((MONTH(recorded_on) = NULL) AND (YEAR(recorded_on) = NULL))  ... ?

Comment: I didn't realise you were using SQLite because you didn't specify. You just need to use the appropriate SQL then. See http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: My bad about not specifying that: also, I think you mis-typed the route above... should start "map.targets_by_month", I think.  Also, along those lines, the route only seems to work with the year ("/targets/2009"); if I supply a month as well, I get an Unknown Route error ("/targets/2009/4"). Any idea why?

Comment: Good catch, I've fixed the route declaration. Does it work with a two digit month?

Comment: Yeah, I figured out what I was doing wrong: I had the route declaration after the default routes ("map.connect ':controller/:action/:id' / map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format' "), when they need to come before.